# VSCode Error: The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/bin/tmux" does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code

After VScode installation, when I tried to open my integrated terminal window, each time I am getting error mentioned in the title.

I don't know what is the correct path to shell-executable. Before VSCode installation, the only change I done in terminal is I installed zsh in it.

System Details -

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- VSCode version: 1.53.2

Answer (score 20):

I solved this issue by changing by default shell for vs-code with following steps:

1. Open settings-search in VSCode with `Cntr + Shift + p`
2. Search for `default`
3. clicked `Terminal: Select Default Shell`
4. clicked `zsh  /usr/bin/zsh`, I selected zsh as I recently installed it and like to use it, you can use other terminal options as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by changing the path of "terminal.integrated.shell.linux" in the settings.json file.
Link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch

Answer (score 2):

The option "terminal.integrated.shell.linux" is deprecated.

The new VSCode config is (mine is 1.62.3 on Ubuntu):

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/zsh",
        }
    },
```

If only "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile." is set, it can not find zsh.

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS 

Answer (score -3):

everyone.
I had a similar issue, but I wasn't able to identify if something was using the port 5432.
That was the way that I solved the issue:

1. I used sudo ss -tulwn | grep LISTEN

> ```
> ➜  xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx git:(main) sudo ss -tulwn | grep LISTEN
> tcp     LISTEN   0        244                                 127.0.0.1:5432                            0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        511                                 127.0.0.1:35613                           0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        100                                 127.0.0.1:49152                           0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        128                                 127.0.0.1:30800                           0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        128                                 127.0.0.1:30900                           0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        4096                            127.0.0.53%lo:53                              0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        5                                   127.0.0.1:631                             0.0.0.0:*                                               
> tcp     LISTEN   0        5                                       [::1]:631                                [::]:*
> ```

2. docker container ls (just checking)

> ➜ xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx git:(main) docker container ls
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

3. docker ps -a  (just checking)

> ```
>  ➜  xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx  git:(main) docker ps -a
>     CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
> ```

4. docker network prune

> ```
> ➜  xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx git:(main) docker network prune
>     WARNING! This will remove all custom networks not used by at least one container.
> ```

**After that, docker-compose down and docker-compose up --build works**

And I was happy using docker... until now.

```
My next steps:
Configure container's environment for the first time
```

5. Run docker-compose run —rm web bash in a separate terminal pane/window. You should now be inside container, which is
   indicated by showing you a hashtag before commands.
6. Run rails db:create within container.
7. Run rails db:migrate within container.
   Run the environment seeds (if you want to)
8. Run rails db:seed.